# Sql like query on array, check if value exists in secondary array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm relatively new to the MEAN stack/Node, and I'm trying to do an operation that I would have found pretty easy in the .Net/RDBMS world:

```
SELECT * FROM Collection1 WHERE Id IN 
(SELECT Collection1Id FROM Collection2 WHERE SomeValue > @Something 
AND SomeOtherValue <@Something)
```

Now in Mongo, I don't have access to do a Join, and the objects are naturally different enough that embedding doesn't make sense. So what I have so far is:

```
Collection1.find({ ..filtering criteria here ...}, function(err, collection1s){

var idsFromCollection1 =[];

//forEach is bad because it's blocking?
collection1s.forEach(function(item){
   idsFromCollection1.push(item.doc._id);
});

//nested callbacks are not ideal but unsure what else to do?
Collection2.find({ "collection1Id" : { $in: idsFromCollection1 },
 { SomeValue : { $gt: something }}, 
 { SomeOtherValue  { $lt: something }} }, 
 function(err, collection2s){

      //do some sort of filter on collection1s where id must be in collection2s 

 });


 });
```

This seems like an incorrect approach, because of multiple callbacks, the blocking foreach and the fact that I don't know how to do a sql like join on the two arrays without looping through collection1 and doing a collection2.contains() for every element... which seems slow and terrible.

So my questions are 1) what's a better approach? 2) if this approach is correct given the problem, how can i do an efficient sql-like join on two arrays in memory?

Comment: Note collection1 is selected from first my example because with what filtering criteria I have, it's less likely to have a large data size, whereas collection2 is expected to be very large.

Comment: That's the main difference between SQL and Mongo, the latter is really just a key/value store, with some added sugar over the years to do more complicated queries, but it's still not a RDBMS. Generally one should choose a DB that fits the use case, and if complicated relational queires is something you'll need often, you're probably using the wrong database, and should be using a relational DB instead

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a complicated query